# How do I fetch firebase data into my individual mat-card in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material

How do I get the data available into an individual mat-card?

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything ? This is a bit broad

Comment: you can get it using .doc("id")

Comment: How. First time trying to fetch data and viewing in card

Comment: Please elaborate a little :) I'll be happy to help!

Comment: @ntrch i want each mat-card to contain details of each restaurant. For example a card will contain the name,email, phone number and address likewise the other cards

Comment: share us some code of yours.

Comment: Refer: https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/firebase-firestore-and-angular-todo-list-application-d0fe760f6bca

Comment: @rijin not what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

https://www.djamware.com/post/5bbf534580aca7466989441c/angular-6-firebase-tutorial-firestore-crud-web-application

I think you'll find a close enough answer there.

I searched for `mat-card` in that page and got:

```
<div class="button-row">
  <a mat-fab color="primary" [routerLink]="['/boards']"><mat-icon>list</mat-icon></a>
</div>
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title><h2>{{board.title}}</h2></mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{board.description}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <dl>
      <dt>ISBN:</dt>
      <dd>{{board.isbn}}</dd>
      <dt>Author:</dt>
      <dd>{{board.author}}</dd>
      <dt>Publisher:</dt>
      <dd>{{board.publisher}}</dd>
      <dt>Publish Year:</dt>
      <dd>{{board.published_year}}</dd>
      <dt>Update Date:</dt>
      <dd>{{board.updated_date | date}}</dd>
        </dl>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <a mat-fab color="primary" [routerLink]="['/board-edit', board.key]"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></a>
    <a mat-fab color="warn" (click)="deleteBoard(board.key)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon> 
    </a>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

And of course, the code before that explains how to bind `board` to your Firebase table.